# Getting the pixel value in masm 8086 assembly language

Tags: assembly, masm, proc, emu8086

I am drawing bricks on masm 8086 assembly language and i wanted to know whether there is any instruction to return the pixel value of the screen.

```
currently there is no code
```

Comment: Video RAM is readable as well as writable, using any instruction you want.  To just load a byte into a register, of course use `mov` on an address in the framebuffer, with a memory source instead of memory destination.

Comment: Are you using MASM or emu8086?  Those are different assemblers (and EMU8086 is also an IDE with a simulator and debugger.)  If you don't have any code, don't include a code block in your question.  But it might be a good idea to show how you're drawing bricks.

Answer (score 0):

> any instruction to return the pixel value of the screen.

Seeing you mention 'drawing bricks' and talking about 'pixels', I understand you are working on a graphical video mode.

I will further assume that this video mode is the 256-color mode 13h (320 x 200), which is the easiest to program and most colorful of the legacy video modes (with mode numbers below 20).

### You can ask BIOS to give you the color of any pixel on the screen

```
; CX is X [0,319]
; DX is Y [0,199]
; -> AL is color [0,255]
; IN (cx,dx) OUT (al) MOD (ah)
GetPixel:
  push bx
  mov  bh, 0        ; DisplayPage
  mov  ah, 0Dh      ; BIOS.GetPixel
  int  10h          ; -> AL
  pop  bx
  ret
```

Relying on BIOS is a safe and compact solution that will also work on any of the other legacy video modes.

### You can read the color of any pixel on the screen yourself

```
; CX is X [0,319]
; DX is Y [0,199]
; -> AL is color [0,255]
; IN (cx,dx) OUT (al) MOD (ah)
GetPixel:
  push ds           ; DirectionFlag (DF) assumed 0
  push bx
  push dx
  mov  ax, 0A000h   ; Video buffer for 256-color mode 13h (320 x 200)
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  ax, 320      ; BytesPerScanline (BPS)
  mul  dx           ; Y * BPS
  add  ax, cx       ; Y * BPS + X
  mov  bx, ax       ; BX is address
  mov  al, [BX]     ; AL is color
  pop  dx
  pop  bx
  pop  ds
  ret
```

Reading the video memory yourself requires more code and is somewhat troublesome in the other legacy video modes but is much faster than using the BIOS function.